# Using parts of piecewise function

Tags: differential-equations, piecewise

I define:

```
 f[x_] := Piecewise[{{5, 0 <= x < 10}, {g[x], 10 <= x < 15}, {h[x], x > 15}}]
```

Then I try to solve ODE:

```
 a = 0.7
 NDSolve[{g'[x] == Sin[x] + 2*With[{t = a*x}, Refine[f[t], 0 <= t < 10]], g[10] == 5},
 g[x], {x, 10, 14.2857}]
```

It gives $g[x]$ as InterpolatingFunction.

Then - plot it:

```
 Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 11}]
```

But it plots $f[x]$ only in {x, 0, 10}, where the function is defined manually. 
So, plotting $g[x]$ also doesn't give any result.
I tried other definitions of Piecewise function (such as $f$), but it also didn't work. Solving ODE for $f[x]$ (not for $g[x]$) is helpless.

So, my question is:
Can I use different undefined parts of Piecewise function for calculations? If not, are there another possibilities to do this in Mathematica maybe?

Answer (score 1):

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{5, 0 <= x < 10}, {g[x], 10 <= x < 15}, {h[x], x > 15}}]

a = 0.7
NDSolve[{g'[x] == Sin[x] + 2*With[{t = a*x}, Refine[f[t], 0 <= t < 10]], g[10] == 5},
 g[x], {x, 10, 14.2857}]

g[x_] = g[x] /. % // First

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 15}]
```

> [image: Plot]

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear[g];

f[x_] = Piecewise[{{5, 0 <= x < 10}, {g[x], 10 <= x < 15}, {h[x], x > 15}}]
```

[image]

```
a = 0.7;
Clear[g];
g[x_] = g[x] /. 
   NDSolve[{g'[x] == Sin[x] + 2*With[{t = a*x}, Refine[f[t], 0 <= t < 10]], 
      g[10] == 5}, g[x], {x, 10, 14.2857}][[1]];

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 11}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

However, `DSolve` can be used rather than `NDSolve`

```
Clear[g];
g[x_] = g[x] /. 
  DSolve[{g'[x] == Sin[x] + 2*With[{t = a*x}, Refine[f[t], 0 <= t < 10]], 
     g[10] == 5}, g[x], x][[1]]
```

> -95 + 10 x + Cos[10] - Cos[x]

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 11}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]